# WebService method returns "undefined" back to javascript, even though it should return a value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have a `WebService's` method that returns `boolean`:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true), ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public bool StartMonitoring()
{
    return Schedule.StartMonitoring();
}
```

This is Schedule class's method:

```
public static bool StartMonitoring()
{
    return true;
}
```

This is `JavaScript's` service call:

```
var success = false;
success = myself.get_Service().StartMonitoring();
alert(success);
```

When pop up is displayed it shows `"undefined"` instead of `true`

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `myself` referring to?

Comment: What happens if you return `true` directly from `StartMonitoring` like this: `public bool StartMonitoring(){ return true; }` - just to see if you actually get any value back.

Comment: I assume, get__Service or StartMonitoring is the service you talked about. Since a service is asynchronous call you cant expect success be true. Try use asynchrouns approach like callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which AJAX proxy technology you are using but I'm pretty sure you need a callback, so your JS code should look more like this:

```
myself.get_Service().StartMonitoring(myCallback);

function myCallback(result)
{
     alert(result);
}
```